# Constructing C# object for the JSON

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I am trying to create a C# objects for the JSON response in my  application. I have the JSON like below

```
 {
"@odata.context": "https://example.com/odata/$metadata#REQ",
"value": [
    {
        "Id": 17,
        "Name": "Req"
    }
  ]
 }
```

I am not sure how to create C# object for the `@odata.context`

```
public class RootObject
    {
        public string @odata.context { get; set; }
        public List<Value> value { get; set; }
    }
```

It throws error in @odata.context

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: Automation for this task is available: http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: @GeorgPatscheider The problem here was that you cannot have special characters in a c# identifier, which is solved in given answers by specifying JSON property name.

Answer (score 6):

That's because identifiers in C# can't have `@` sign. You haven't stated what library you're using, but if it's [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) then you can simply decorate the properties.

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
    public string OdataContext { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public List<Value> Value { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: JSON.NET is case insensitive.  You can remove all `JsonProperty` and keep only `[JsonProperty("@odata.context")]`

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft.Json how can I resolve this then

Comment: @aloisdg Good point, but it's just there as a demonstration to OP about decorating properties

Comment: @user4912134 They're the same thing, the code above should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend the use of [Newtonsoft Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

You can find also tons of samples on the documentation page. This one is exactly the solution for your problem (i have added the problematic field ´@odata.context` so that you can understand how to map between JSON response and your class:

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

```
public class Account
{
    [JsonProperty("@odata.context")]
    public string myText { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
}


string json = @"{
  '@odata.context': 'this is an attribute with an @ in the name.',
  'Active': true,
  'CreatedDate': '2013-01-20T00:00:00Z',
  'Roles': [
    'User',
    'Admin'
  ]
}";

Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(json);

Console.WriteLine(account.myText);
// this is an attribute with an @ in the name.
```

Prevent using "@" for your property namens. Instead use `JsonProperty`. This enables you to map a JsonProperty to one of your class fields (in this case it maps the JSON property @odata.context to the myText property of you class.

Comment: How is this answer different to mine, especially since you later edited yours to copy the relevant information from my answer? Your JSON and classes don't even match the question properly...

Comment: I think we have posted just at the same time, so that there is maybe no difference. I wasnt expecting that the poster is using Newstonsoft Json, so that i have first posted an complete "tutorial" for the deserialization. I already mentioned in my first post just `Prevent using "@" for your property namens` but added the JsonProperty later to have an answer which i nearly the one what the poster requested. I do not need to copy your answer !

Comment: No, you posted (copied and pasted) a totally invalid answer that missed the only important part which was the property decoration. You edited it 10 minutes later to copy the relevant part from my answer and your class/JSON is _still_ invalid!

Comment: No it is not invalid. I am checking my code in VS before i post it! Whats your problem?

Comment: Look at the JSON and class in the question, then look at yours. Is it even remotely the same? No... My problem is that you're answer is both plagiarised and wrong. Since we all moderate the site I'm calling you out on it.

Comment: Right, it is not the class that the user has posted. But it was not my intention to copy and paste the class of the OP cause everyone should be able to understand it. And I HAVE NOT PLAGIIARISED you code. Look at my previous answers, you will never see a plagiarised code. I think you should stop whingeing and again: there is nothing wrong in my answer.

Comment: you make me want to plagiarise both of your answers in a more elegant and complete new answer and then encourage OP to accept it because of its completness